# How to replace value of column with MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I try to make some changes to my MySQL database, and I need to change values of this col name "id_lang" which values now is "6" to change to value "2".

This col is found in many tables, it will be great to have a single query which will to this for all DB at once.

by now i found this query,

```
SELECT REPLACE(yourcolumn,'ValueInTheColumnTobeReplaced', 'NewValue')  as replacedColumnName FROM yourtable
```

PS: I use PHPMYADMIN

but i cant make it work... PLease help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an `Update` query.

But you can not do this in one query for all tables.

```
Update yourTable set id_lang=2  where id_lang=6
```

Comment: @Andrei Sorry changed my answer

Comment: Well, you can always join them!

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
 UPDATE yourTable SET id_lang=2 WHERE id_lang=6;
```

Comment: The inverted commas are slow and unnecessary. I removed them.

Comment: I concur, they are optional in the case of integers...hope the query fixed your problem.